# MYSQL multiple tables in one query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

There are two tables named Customers and Payments. 
They both have the "CustomerNumber"

Here's what i am trying to do.

```
Select checkNumber, amount, CustomerNumber, CustomerName
FROM Payments, Customers
```

And i get an error saying : `Unknown column`....` in 'field list'

I also tried doing this query

```
Select checkNumber, amount, Payments.CustomerNumber, CustomerName
FROM Payments, Customers
```

It didn't work T_T

i tried this one

Select `checkNumber`, `amount`, `customerNumber`, `customerName` 
FROM `payments`, `customers`

I get this error "Column 'customerNumber' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: Can you add the exact SQL query to your post?

Comment: Please add the real code and real table names.  As is I'm tempted to close as too vague.

Comment: `CustomerName` != `customerName`.

Comment: There, i just edited it and put the real table names. Sorry about that

Comment: You can use Alias to get your answer!!!

Comment: @Barranka that didn't work too.

Comment: BTW you're mixing upper/lower case in your SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your tables named `1` and `2`?

If they are, then mysql is probably not recognizing 1 and 2 as table names, but as numbers. Try enclosing the table names with backticks:

```
select `1`.CustomerName, lastName, street, state
from `1`, `2`
```

By the way, this will give you every possible combination of rows... be careful (or use a `join`)

---

UPDATE

Given the new data in your comment:

Check the field names... field names must be written *exactly* as the names in the table(s). Notice that you're writing `payments.customerNumber` in the `select` section and `payments.customersNumber` in the `from` section

Comment: SELECT `checkNumber`, `amount`, `payments.customerNumber`, `customers.customerName` FROM `payments`
INNER JOIN `Customers`
ON payments.customersNumber=customers.customersNumber

----------This is what im doing right now and im still getting an error and no they arent named 1 and 2. Those are just examples.

Comment: that didn't work. I just checked the spelling again. like you said it was wrong. But that didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

This error happends when there're 2 columns with the same name in 2 tables, so you have to specify the same column in which table, i.e :

```
Select checkNumber, amount, Customers.CustomerNumber, CustomerName
FROM Payments, Customers
```

or try to make all of your table name and column quoted in ` like this:

> ```
> Select `checkNumber`, `amount`, `Payments.CustomerNumber`, `CustomerName`
> FROM `Payments`, `Customers`
> ```

Comment: be aware that MySQL is case sensitive with table names when the MySQL server being used is hosted on a Linux machine. 

`SELECT checkNumber, amount, Customers.CustomerNumber, CustomerName
FROM Payments, Customers WHERE Customers.CustomerNumber = Payments.CustomerNumber'

should definitely work. The WHERE clause, or the JOIN clause as posted earlier is highly recommended when u want to read the correct payments for the customers :)